# Throttle but discard results if they come too late

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactiveui, rx.net

I'm writing a UI where the user can type in a search term and a list get continuously updated offering suggestions.

My first though was that the Rx primitive Throttle was a perfect match but it gets me half there.

The suggestions take a while to fetch so I get them asynchronously on not on the UI thread.

The problem is that I want to discard/skip/throw away a result if the user types af the throttle time span again.

For example:

- Time starts and the user presses a key : 0ms
- The throttle is set to 100ms.
- The fetch takes 200ms.
- At 150ms the user pressed another key

Now with Throttle the first fetch will still go ahead an populate the gui suggestion list.
What I like to learn is how can I cancel that first fetch as it is not relevant anymore?
Only the second keypress should trigger an update to the gui.

Here is what I tried

(I use ReactiveUI but the Q is about Rx)

```
public IEnumerable<usp_getOpdrachtgevers_Result> Results { get; set; } // [Reactive] pu

public SearchOpdrachtgeverVM()
{

    this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.FirstName,
                      x => x.LastName
        )
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
        .Subscribe(async vm => Results = await PopulateGrid());
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<usp_getOpdrachtgevers_Result>> PopulateGrid()
{

    return await Task.Run(
             () => _opdrachtgeversCache
                         .Where(x =>
                                x.vNaam.Contains(FirstName)
                                && x.vLastName.Contains(LastName)
                         )

             );

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you turn your async Task into an Observable, this looks like a classic use for `Switch`:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.FirstName,
                  x => x.LastName
    )
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)) 
    .Select(l => PopulateGrid().ToObservable())
    .Switch()
    .Subscribe(vm => Results = vm);
```

`Throttle` should be used to suppress calls while the user is typing. So adjust that TimeSpan as you like.

Comment: Aah the switch yes. That's a primitive that could be usefull when I read about it and this can fit. I'll give it a go tomorrow.
The definition of switch : Transforms an observable sequence of observable sequences into an observable sequence producing values only from the most recent observable sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, this can be done in a quite straight forward manner and clean if you refactor your code slightly.

Firstly, make the first name and last name triggers into observables. In the code below, I have used subjects but it is better if you're able to use static Observable methods to 'convert' them into observables; e.g. `Observable.FromEvent`.

Then turn the code to fetch results into an observable. In the code below I have used `Observable.Create` to return a stream of `IEnumerable<string>`.

Finally, you can use the Switch operator to subscribe to each new GetResults call and cancel the previous call to GetResults.

Sounds complicated but the code is quite straight forward:

```
private Subject<string> _firstName = new Subject<string>();
private Subject<string> _lastName = new Subject<string>();

private Task<IEnumerable<string>> FetchResults(string firstName, string lastName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Fetch the results, respecting the cancellation token at the earliest opportunity
    return Task.FromResult(Enumerable.Empty<string>());
}

private IObservable<IEnumerable<string>> GetResults(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    return Observable.Create<IEnumerable<string>>(
        async observer =>
        {
            // Use a cancellation disposable to provide a cancellation token the the asynchronous method
            // When the subscription to this observable is disposed, the cancellation token will be cancelled.
            CancellationDisposable disposable = new CancellationDisposable();

            IEnumerable<string> results = await FetchResults(firstName, lastName, disposable.Token);

            if (!disposable.IsDisposed)
            {
                observer.OnNext(results);
                observer.OnCompleted();
            }

            return disposable;
        }
    );
}

private void UpdateGrid(IEnumerable<string> results)
{
    // Do whatever
}

private IDisposable ShouldUpdateGridWhenFirstOrLastNameChanges()
{
    return Observable
        // Whenever the first or last name changes, create a tuple of the first and last name
        .CombineLatest(_firstName, _lastName, (firstName, lastName) => new { FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName })
        // Throttle these tuples so we only get a value after it has settled for 100ms
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
        // Select the results as an observable
        .Select(tuple => GetResults(tuple.FirstName, tuple.LastName))
        // Subscribe to the new results and cancel any previous subscription
        .Switch()
        // Use the new results to update the grid
        .Subscribe(UpdateGrid);
}
```

Quick tip: you should really pass an explicit scheduler into the Throttle so that you can effectively unit test this code using the TestScheduler.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The `WhenAnyValue` method is ReactiveUI short-hand for all that subjecty code you're suggesting.

Comment: Hi @ibebbs. As Shlomo noted I use ReactiveUI to eliminate some of the plumbing. I really appreciate your answer by writing it out though! And the tip about the scheduler is something I will look in too as well.

Comment: It seems that this is a text book example http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html#Switch

Comment: From http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/switch.html This subtle behavioir seems important:
"Note that it will unsubscribe from the previously-emitted Observable when a new Observable is emitted from the source Observable, not when the new Observable emits an item."
The implementation could as well be  that the unsubscription happens once an item is emitted (quod non). The chosen behavior is what is need in this scenario.