# Rx.NET throttling with cancellation

Tags: task-parallel-library, system.reactive, rx.net

I have a question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149713/throttle-but-discard-results-if-they-come-too-late). I need to handle series of user input events (searches) in the following way:

- throttle every search phrase with N-miliseconds
- cancel previously run search if the search phrase changed (and new search is about to be run)
- apply only the latest search

My code seems to work almost this way except the cancelling.

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventArgs>(
    handler => SearchBox.TextChanged += handler,
    handler => SearchBox.TextChanged -= handler)
.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
.Select(GetSearchQuery)
.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(MinimumSearchIntervalMiliseconds))
.DistinctUntilChanged()
.Subscribe(ExecuteSearch, () => { });
```

`string GetSearchQuery(EventPattern<TextChangedEventArgs>)` returns search string and `void ExecuteSearch(string)` runs search.

For some reason I cannot find the `Switch()` extension mentioned in all the answers on SO...

I'm using `System.Reactive` and `System.Reactive.Linq` in version `4.0.0`

I guess that `Select()` and `Subscribe()` in this form is not the best solution in the code above. They should probably operate on `Task`s...

Any idea how can I improve the pipeline above to support cancelling as required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing here, but you probably have `ExecuteSearch` sending out the search string, getting results, then binding them to UI. Split up `ExecuteSearch` to return ideally `IObservable<Results>` or `Task<Results>` and a new function `public void ApplySearchResults(Results r)` to handle the UI binding.

Once you have that, this should work:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventArgs>(
    handler => SearchBox.TextChanged += handler,
    handler => SearchBox.TextChanged -= handler)
.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
.Select(GetSearchQuery)
.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(MinimumSearchIntervalMiliseconds))
.DistinctUntilChanged()
.Select(ExecuteSearch /* .ToObservable() if it returns Task<Results>/*)
.Switch()
.Subscribe(ApplyResults, () => { })
```

`.Switch` works on `IObservable<IObservable<T>>`. You didn't have a double-observable, just a single one, which is why you weren't seeing it.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for